# How to restrict TestMain(m *testing.M) to the current test file

Tags: go, testing

Is it possible to restrict a `func TestMain(m *testing.M) {}` to the current test file, instead of to all test files in the same package?

Suppose in `package blah` I have the two test files:

`blah_test.go`:

```golang
package blah

import "testing"

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    // do something fancy
}

// all my blah tests that depend on TestMain()...
```

`arg_test.go`:

```golang
package blah

import "testing"

// all my arg tests that don't depend on TestMain()...
```

Since both of these test files are in the same package, `TestMain()` gets called before all `blah_test.go` tests *(which is expected)*, and before all of my `arg_test.go` tests *(this was unexpected)*. I'd love to have `TestMain()` only trigger for the current test file it's in, instead of to the entire package but can't see anything that suggests this is possible.

I attempted replacing `TestMain()` with an `init()`, but that does the same thing *(which was also unexpected)*. Anything I can do here besides creating my own function in `blah_test.go` and updating all `blah_test.go` tests to hit that func?

Comment: Why can't you call all tests from `TestMain`? It's essentially the normal mode of operation, just gives you a hook into what is normally called internally by the testing package. Otherwise, the usual build constrains work just fine on test files too, which are the only way to differentiate files within a package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go test works on packages not files. You cannot do what you want.

Comment: Haha, that makes sense. I just recently discovered/used `TestMain` and got hung up on it's use that I didn't consider this. Thank you!